# Delete many rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am deleting rows in order of hundreds of thousands from a remote DB.  Each delete has it's own target eg.

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE (col1=c1val1 AND col2=c2val1) OR (col1=c1val2 AND col2=c2val2) OR ...
```

This has been almost twice as fast for me than individual queries, but I was wondering if there's a way to speed this up more, as I haven't been working with SQL very long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a temporary table and fill it with all your value pairs, one per row.  Name the columns the same as the matching columns in your `table`.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE donotwant (
  col1 INT NOT NULL,
  col2 INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (c1val, c2val)
);

INSERT INTO donotwant VALUES (c1val1, c2val1), (c1val2, c2val2), ...
```

Then execute a multi-table delete based on the JOIN between these tables:

```
DELETE t1 FROM `tablename` AS t1 JOIN `donotwant` USING (col1, col2);
```

The USING clause is shorthand for `ON t1.col1=donotwant.col1 AND t1.col2=donotwant.col2`, assuming the columns are named the same in both tables, and you want the join condition where both columns are equal to their namesake in the joined table.

Comment: How is the temp table dealt with afterwards?

Comment: Temp tables are dropped automatically when the session that created them ends.

Comment: I seem to have trouble making this work, can you clarify the syntax of your last line?

Comment: @Subbarker, I edited the above to be specific and use the same table name `tablename` as in your original question.  Of course, change this to the real name of the table you want to delete from.  I tested this on MySQL 5.5 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the fastest way to do bulk `DELETE`s is to put the ids to be deleted into a temp table of some sort, then use that as part of the query:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE (col1, col2) IN (SELECT col1, col2
                       FROM tmp)
```

Inserting can be done via a standard:

```
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (...), (...), ...;
```

statement, or by using the DB's bulk-load utility.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it makes much difference to performance but you can write that kind of thing this way...

```
DELETE 
  FROM table
 WHERE (col1,col2) IN(('c1val1','c2val1'),('c1val2','c2val2')...);
```